# User Creation in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication

One of my client need a internet published SharePoint Portal for his customers, he want to give credentials to his customer to login in that portal but do not want to create those credential in his AD.

I went through the archived questions and found that a Database with membership table is a solutions for it.

I am looking for any another solutions for it, as my client is not allowing me to create the database!!

Any suggestion !!

Comment: The emerging trend for external collaboration is to use SharePoint Online where external user credentials are not handled by your organization, but by Microsoft. You can share with external users and force them to log in with a Microsoft account (like live.com) or an existing Office 365 account.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try integrating your SharePoint site with any other popular external providers such as Facebook,Google, Microsoft Live ID etc and authenticate user's by Federated authentication mechanism.

You can refer this [blog](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22309.integrating-windows-live-id-google-and-facebook-accounts-with-sharepoint-2013-white-paper.aspx) for more details on it.